# Relations between two versions of PCA

Tags: statistics, matrix-calculus

I have seen two versions of Standard/Classical Principal Component Ananlysis. And I have no idea how they are related:

**Version 1 :**[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).

This is about solving the eigen vectors and eigen values.

The first principal component $ \omega_{1} $ is defined as ：
$$\omega_{1}=\underset{||\omega||=1}{\mathrm{arg~~ max}}~~Var\{\omega^{T}X\}=\underset{||\omega||=1}{\mathrm{arg~~ max}}~~ E\{(\omega^{T}X)^{2}\}
$$
the $k_{th}$ principal component is computed as the following：
$$
\hat{X}_{k-1}=X-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\omega_{i}\omega_{i}^{T}X
$$
$$
\omega_{k}=\underset{||\omega||=1}{\mathrm{arg~~ max}}~~ E\{(\omega^{T}\hat{X}_{k-1})^{2}\}
$$

**Version 2 :**[Paper: Robust principal component analysis? by EJ Candes, et al](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/RobustPCA.pdf).

> this says that if we stack all the data points as column vectors of a
>   matrix M, the matrix should (approximately) have low rank:
>   mathematically,$$ M = L_{0} + N_{0}, $$where $L_{0}$ has low-rank and $N_{0}$ is a small
>   perturbation matrix. Classical Principal Component Analysis (PCA)
>   [Hotelling 1933; Eckart and Young 1936; Jolliffe 1986] seeks the best
>   (in an 2 sense) rank-k estimate of $L_{0}$ by solving $$    \underset{subject~~ to ~~rank(L) ≤ k}{ minimize~~|| M − L||} $$ 
>   subject to $rank(L) ≤ k$. (Throughout this article, $||M||$ denotes the
>   2-norm; that is, the largest singular value of M.)

It will greatly appreciated if anyone could answer my questions!

Comment: The fact(s) that the subspace generated from PCA (a) maximizes the captured variance, (b) consists of the top eigenvectors (c) minimizes the L^2 error in multiplying against the data matrix are all very classical, and e.g., are outlined in the first couple of pages from these slides (first Google result): http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/teaching/3f3/1011/lect5.pdf

Comment: There is a statistics website, see the list elsewhere on this page.